# Legend in species accumulation plots

Tags: r, graph, legend, vegan

How can I add a caption to this graph?
I tried the commands below but my graph disappeared

```
library(vegan)
data(BCI)

sp1 <- specaccum(BCI, "random")
sp2 <- specaccum(BCI, "coleman")

plot(sp1, ci.type="poly", col="blue", lwd=2,
     ci.lty=0, ci.col = rgb(.5, .5, .5, 0.5))
plot(sp2, ci.type="poly", col="yellow",lwd=2,
     ci.lty=0, ci.col = rgb(.5, .5, .5, 0.5), add=TRUE)
legend(x="top", legend=sp1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why your plot is disappearing is that you are trying to create a legend containing the entire contents of `sp1`, which is a large numerical object. Presumably that's not what you want, and you're only looking for the *text* "sp1" to appear in the legend. You need to specify a vector of the strings you would like added as labels in your legend, as well as a vector the colours.

Note I have also added a title to this plot using `main = "sp1"` in the *first* call to `plot`:

```r
library(vegan)
data(BCI)

sp1 <- specaccum(BCI, "random")
sp2 <- specaccum(BCI, "coleman")

plot(sp1, ci.type="poly", col="blue", lwd=2,
     ci.lty=0, ci.col = rgb(.5, .5, .5, 0.5), main = "sp1")
plot(sp2, ci.type="poly", col="yellow",lwd=2,
     ci.lty=0, ci.col = rgb(.5, .5, .5, 0.5), add = TRUE)
legend(x = "bottomright", legend = c("sp1", "sp2"), fill = c("blue", "yellow"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>